# Taking time to read from properties file

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular JS. I am facing one issue. Please see the below issue description.

**applicationLabel.properties:**

```
{
 "globalLabel":
 {
   "name" : "testName",
   "address" : "testAddress"
 }
}
```

**Controller File :**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('applicationLabel.properties').then(function (response) {
    var applicationLabels = response.globalLabel;
  });
});
```

**Issue Description :**

I am able to fetch values from property file properly. But problem is that angular js taking too much time to load the property file into controller and reflect those values to respective html file. It is taking more than 3 seconds to render completely. When I am facing this issue when using this functionality for website development.

Is there any way to speed up the processing of same functionality or there is another approach to fetch data other than property file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For what purpose do you use *.properties file?

Comment: Are you sur it's angular that take time ? Your http request can be the slower ?

Comment: No static/hard-coded data should be there in html or controller file. So when in feature we need to change the data/label/value as per, client/customer, need then instead of going to each and every file we should modify only single file and values will get reflected to all the pages.

Comment: @Silvinus Yeah. Its taking more than 3 seconds to render values on html page.

Comment: why don't you use .json file instead of .properties file and try this. if it's also takes time maybe ur http request might be slow

Comment: @IT13122256RanawakaR.A.S.M I tried .json instead of .properties file. It also doesn't solve the problem. I will try with another approach you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

https://plnkr.co/edit/9XLaHG9rIXHLY1HGd7Ly?p=preview

```
app.controller('test', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.pp="Pankaj";
  $http.get('app.properties').then(function (response) {
    var applicationLabels = response.globalLabel;
  });
});
```

it took only 391ms to load this(app.properties) file.You can have a look..

Check in the network using inspect element option

Comment: Please try to load value "Pankaj" from property file and set it to controller variable $scope.pp = [ValueFromPropertyFile]. It is taking time to load.